# Back press not working inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

Question: How do I enable my back button to return to my previous hosting activity/fragment?

Situation: My launcher activity hosts a fragment while also contains a FAB. Clicking on the FAB launches a second activity which hosts another fragment. When the latter fragment is shown, a searchView is automatically expanded with focus on it. Pressing back closes the keypad. However, pressing back again does not return me to my launcher activity.

Things I've tried:

In my hosting activity

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,   fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DOWN) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

In fragment

```
frag.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
frag.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ){
       if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ){
            return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
} );
```

Also I've noticed that pressing the back button doesn't call either onBackPressed nor onKeyDown.

Comment: how about to remove `setOnKeyListener` in Fragment?

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same. There is no response from the back button. I also tried overriding finish() in the activity with a log message inside. Nothing gets printed.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I removed the only listener in my fragment (searchView.setOnQueryTextListener), but the back button still does not respond.

Comment: I managed to narrow down the source of the problem but I can't figure out how to move around it. The problem seems to stem from searchView.onActionExpanded(). When my searchView is fully expanded, the back button does not respond. But when I comment out that line, the back button works. However, I want the searchView to be fully expanded at all time so I don't know how to resolve this.